# Posterior density for θ - Gamma(α, β)

Tags: probability, statistics

I want to find the posterior density for $\theta$ with a prior Gamma distribution $(\alpha, \beta)$.

$$
f(x\mid\theta) = \frac 1 2 \theta e^{-\theta |x|}, \quad -\infty < x < \infty
$$

From what I know the posterior is proportional to the Likelihood ($L_n(\theta)$) times the prior $f(\theta)$ since the random variables are iid.

Comment: The Poison distribution is _discrete_.  Clearly the posterior will not be a discrete distribution. $\qquad$

Comment: What is preventing you to compute the product $f(x\mid\theta)f(\theta)$ (once you will have corrected $f(x\mid\theta)$...)?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ok this thought was based on papers I read that proved it the other way around i.e. from a Poison prior, to a Gamma posterior. Hence I made this false assumption..

Comment: @Did well the distribution confuses me. I'm unsure how to interpret the function that I have specified above with the help of the properties of a Gamma distribution.

Comment: Then, stop trying to interpret - just compute! What is the PDF of $\theta$, already?

Comment: @Flo : Maybe it was the DATA that had a Poisson distribution in those papers you looked at.

Comment: Did you have in mind the Gamma distribution with a factor of $e^{-\theta/\beta}$, or the form with $e^{-\theta\beta}$? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think the latter, since I have Gamma($\alpha, \beta$) thus the pdf for this distribution concerns with $\e^-\theta\beta$ if I'm sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
L_n(\theta) = \text{constant}\times \theta^n e^{-\theta(|x_1|+\cdots+|x_n|)}.
$$
The prior is
$$
\theta\mapsto \text{constant}\times \theta^{\alpha-1} e^{-\theta/\beta}.
$$
Multiplying these, one gets
$$
\text{constant}\times \theta^{n+\alpha-1} e^{-\theta(|x_1|+\cdots + |x_n| + 1/\beta)}.
$$
So the posterior distribution is a Gamma distribution.  Where one had $\alpha$ one now has $\alpha+n$ and where one had $\beta$ one now has $\dfrac 1 {|x_1|+\cdots+|x_n| + \frac 1 \beta}$.